# Android onClickListener on list item in fragment to dislay custom dialogue

Tags: android, android-listview, dialog, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I want to open a custom dialog when a list item is clicked. How can I implement `onClickListener` to my code:

```
public class Fragment4 extends Fragment{
    private View parentLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> myList;
    private AboutUsAdapter adapter; //custom adapter

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        parentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_4, null);
        listView = (ListView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView4);
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myList.add("Item1");
        myList.add("Item2");
        myList.add("Item2");
        adapter = new AboutUsAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), myList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return parentLayout;
            }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {            
    }

}); } }
```

Comment: have you tried using the AlertDialogBuilder? it is very easy and does what you are looking for!

Comment: thats fine, but how do i register to specific item click in this case ?

Comment: im not quite sure what you are looking for, maybe the reference for the listview-item?  thats getPostion() then.

Comment: can you please post the code according to the my code how to open dialogbox by clicking on particular itemlist say Item1.
i am new to android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this way...

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {  

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("Your title here");
    alert.setMessage(myList.get(position).toString());
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

    alert.show();          
}});
```

For same way you can use your custom dialog

change your line

```
parentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_4, null);
```

to

```
parentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_4, container,false);
```

Comment: how do i pass the selected item position in arguments

Comment: You can simple pass "position" which is int Varible...And if you get your item name then see in my post that i have set message so you can get position wise name.... like if you click on Item1 then dialog open with Item1 name....and etc..

Comment: whenever i try to add this code ...it is crashing and restarting the app with NullPointer Exception in logcat

Comment: PLease post your logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a clickListener for your list items like this:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
            // show your dialog here
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sayed , will this code open same dialog for every item in the list ? 
i want different content in dialogs for different item in list .
thanks

Comment: You can display different content for all of them. All you need is an identifier for which item in the list is clicked. to get the clicked item, do this inside the onItemClick method : String item =  listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

Comment: Between if you have more content to show than just a simple string, you should be using custom adapters. have a look at this blog post http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html